# How to sort by second char?

Tags: java, sorting, char

I am newbie in Java and i have to do this task for an institute

I have a code and it have to sort words in input String by Alphabet by second char.
So, can anybody tell my how to do sort?

Comment: What part of this are you having problems with? You're providing way too much code, you should reduce your code sample. Remove anything not directly related to your problem, like input/output or splitting the string; leave only the parts where you're already trying to sort a list of words.

Comment: @millimoose This is code without sorting. I just dont know to do sort at all

Comment: Have you read the thousand pages that Google returns when searching for "sort objects in java"?

Comment: @JB Nizet Yes, but i dont know how to sotr by second char

Comment: @antoxa2584 Why post a hundred lines of code that have nothing to do with your question then? And if you don't even have a `List<String>` anywhere, then "sorting words" isn't your actual problem, since there's nothing to sort yet.

Comment: @millimoose But, can I use StringTokenizer to srot?

Comment: *"I am newbie in Java and i have to do this task for an institute"* - It sounds like you have been employed to do a job that you don't have the skills to do.  You should discuss this with your boss, and get him to set aside some time / resources for you to train up in Java programming.  I'm afraid we can't (won't) do your programming for you.

Comment: @ Stephen C I just asked about help in 2/10 of my program

Comment: @antoxa2584 No, you can use StringTokenizer to split a string into tokens. (Which can easily be words.) You can sort the resulting list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort *only* by the second `char` then just use a custom comparator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("adaaa");
    strings.add("bbaaa");
    strings.add("dcaaaa");
    strings.add("zaaaaa");
    Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Character.compare(o1.charAt(1), o2.charAt(1));
        }
    });
    System.out.println(strings);
}
```

Output:

```
[zaaaaa, bbaaa, dcaaaa, adaaa]
```

Comment: Can it be done simplier and in 1.6 jdk?

Comment: What do you mean by simpler? I'm sure your capable of adding the generic parameters in and boxing the `char`s so that it works on 1.6.

Comment: Never mind)
Can you write, i dont anderstand, what you mean..